# How can I reuse this express function I wrote but to accept an array as the parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-loop, mongoose

**I have a function I wrote that returns a json of an Order,finds details by Id below is the Code and Model,I want it to accept an array of ids and return to me the Json all together.I have an array of addresses i want to substitute to the code below to give output in JSON**

**Function I would Like to Reuse If Possible**:

```
exports.getOrder = (req, res, next) => {
  let addressArray = [];
  Order.findById(//I want it to accept an array of Id)
    .then((order) => {
      console.log(order);
      var arr2 = Object.values(order);
      const newarray = arr2[3];
      const documents = Object.values(newarray);
      newdoc = documents.slice(0, 5);
      return newdoc;

    })
    .then((addressto) => {
      return Promise.all(
        addressto[0].map((item) => {
          return Address.findById(item)
            .then((foundaddress) => {
              const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
              fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
              addressArray.push(fullItemData);

            })
            .then((a) => {
              addressto[1].map((item) => {
                return Address.findById(item).then((foundaddress) => {
                  const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                  fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                  addressArray.push(fullItemData);
                  console.log(addressArray);
                  // const source = ["Receiver Address"];
                  // const result = source.map((value) => ({ [value]: addressArray }));
                });
              });
            })
            .then((a) => {
              addressto[2]
                .map((item) => {
                  return Package.findById(item)
                    .then((foundaddress) => {
                      const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                      fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                      addressArray.push(fullItemData);

                      addressArray.push(addressto[4]);
                      console.log(addressto);
                      console.log(addressArray);
                      return addressArray;
                    })
                    .then((a) => {
                      res.send(a);
                    });
                })
                .then((a) => {
                  res.send(a);
                });
            });
        })
      ).then((a) => {
        res.status(200).json(addressArray);
      });
    });
};
```

**My Try**

```
function getOrdera(array) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    const element = array[index];
    exports.getOrder = (req, res, next) => {
      let addressArray = [];
      Order.findById(element)
        .then((order) => {
          console.log(order);
          var arr2 = Object.values(order);
          const newarray = arr2[3];
          const documents = Object.values(newarray);
          newdoc = documents.slice(0, 5);
          return newdoc;
          // res.send(newdoc);
        })
        .then((addressto) => {
          return Promise.all(
            addressto[0].map((item) => {
              return Address.findById(item)
                .then((foundaddress) => {
                  const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                  fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                  addressArray.push(fullItemData);
                  // const source = ["Receiver Address"];
                })
                .then((a) => {
                  addressto[1].map((item) => {
                    return Address.findById(item).then((foundaddress) => {
                      const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                      fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                      addressArray.push(fullItemData);
                      console.log(addressArray);
                      // const source = ["Receiver Address"];
                      // const result = source.map((value) => ({ [value]: addressArray }));
                    });
                  });
                })
                .then((a) => {
                  addressto[2]
                    .map((item) => {
                      return Package.findById(item)
                        .then((foundaddress) => {
                          const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                          fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                          addressArray.push(fullItemData);

                          addressArray.push(addressto[4]);
                          console.log(addressto);
                          console.log(addressArray);
                          return addressArray;
                        })
                        .then((a) => {
                          res.send(a);
                        });
                    })
                    .then((a) => {
                      res.send(a);
                    });
                });
            })
          ).then((a) => {
            res.status(200).json(addressArray);
          });
        });
    };
  }

  // let iray = [];
  // if (array.length > 1) {
  //   array.forEach((item) => {iray.push(item)});
  // }
}
```

**Model:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const OrderSchema = new Schema({
  Address_to: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User_Adress",
    },
  ],

  Address_from: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User_Adress",
    },
  ],
  Package_Details: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Order_Package",
    },
  ],
  Carrier_Details: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Carriers",
    },
  ],

  customer: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "_Users",
    required: true,
  },
  status:{
    type:String,
    required:true,
    default:"SHIPPED"
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User_Orders", OrderSchema);
```

Comment: use ```$in``` and ```find``` instead of ```findbyId``` : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: I want to reuse the function above in another function to accept an array of ids as a parameter to get me full JSON data,The function above is working well @VahidAlimohamadi

Comment: Then make an array up with one element when there is one id.
something like this: ```if (!Array.isArray(ids)) ids = [ids]```

Comment: I needed to put the whole array that contains `ID's` as a `parameter` to the `function` to get me results for the whole array `for each ID` in the Array in JSON form but after completing the search for all values in the Array @VahidAlimohamadi

Comment: I tried the Code Putting a single Id it worked now I want to Put an array to get a total JSON result of the ID's in the Array @VahidAlimohamadi

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach array in other property, and start looping it.

**other file:**

```
anyHttpRequest.body= [id,id2,id3...];
mycontroller.getOrder(anyHttpRequest);
```

**mycontroller:**

handle the checkpoint 1,2, in line:2,line:3

```js
exports.getOrder = (req, res, next) => {
 const idsArray = req.body;  // checkpoint 1
 for(id in idsArray){ // checkpoint 2
  Order.findById(id).then((order) => {
      console.log(order);
      var arr2 = Object.values(order);
      const newarray = arr2[3];
      const documents = Object.values(newarray);
      newdoc = documents.slice(0, 5);
      return newdoc;
    }).then((addressto) => {
      return Promise.all(addressto[0].map((item) => {
          return Address.findById(item).then((foundaddress) => {
              const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
              fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
              addressArray.push(fullItemData);
            }).then((a) => {
              addressto[1].map((item) => {
                return Address.findById(item).then((foundaddress) => {
                  const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                  fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                  addressArray.push(fullItemData);
                  console.log(addressArray);
                  // const source = ["Receiver Address"];
                  // const result = source.map((value) => ({ [value]: addressArray }));
                });
              });
            }).then((a) => {addressto[2]
                .map((item) => {return Package.findById(item)
                    .then((foundaddress) => {
                      const fullItemData = foundaddress.toJSON();
                      fullItemData.occurrences = item.occurrences;
                      addressArray.push(fullItemData);
                      addressArray.push(addressto[4]);
                      console.log(addressto);
                      console.log(addressArray);
                      return addressArray;
                    })
                    .then((a) => {
                      res.send(a);
                    });
                })
                .then((a) => {
                  res.send(a);
                });
            });
        })
      ).then((a) => {
        res.status(200).json(addressArray);
      });
    });
} 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i got undefined in console `anyHttpRequest.body= [id,id2,id3...];
mycontroller.getOrder(anyHttpRequest);` These two lines you wrote what is the anyHttpRequest.body it gives a value of undefined

Comment: you need to manually define it. `anyHttpRequest ` is the request object your will receive on request, append the new property: `anyHttpRequest.body` with some value then fetch it back while looping